# Handle AJAX POST request to render a template in django

Tags: django, ajax

I have a problem when making a site with django, I hope you guys can give me a help. After using an AJAX POST, I will get that data to a function in view.py and do my stuff. It works nice, but when I need to render a template with data of my stuff, the browser does not direct me to that template. Can anyone tell me what should I do to handle the AJAX POST request. Thanks a lot and have a nice day.

view.py:

```
def get_id_from_ajax(request):
print(request)
if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
    print(type(request.POST))
    QueryID = request.POST['key']
    print('data recieved: '+ QueryID)

    if type(int(QueryID)) == int:
        Query_user = allusers.objects.get(id = QueryID)
        Query_username = Query_user.username
        Query_teamID = Query_user.teamid
        Query_rank = Query_user.rank
        Query_status = Query_user.is_deleted

        #return HttpResponseRedirect(json.dumps({'username': Query_username}))
        #return edit_user(request)
        #return JsonResponse(json.dumps({'username': Query_username}), safe=False)
        return render(request, 'edit_user.html',{"username": Query_username, "teamid": Query_teamID, "rank": Query_rank, "status": Query_status})
        #return redirect('edit_user.html')
return render(request, 'edit_user.html')
```

ajax post:

```
 btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
var testID = this.id;
var getID = testID.match(/\d/g);
getID = getID.join("");
console.log(getID);

e.preventDefault();
$.post('/testdb/get_id_from_ajax', {
  key: getID,
  csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
});
```

I just need to render a new template with data I got in my view.py. Thank you guys for any help.

Comment: Your redirect is commented out in your view. What error do you get?

Comment: if I use redirect, the post request will return error code 302 and the browser still have no change.